# Toyota Avensis Verso 2002 (sold in Italy) CLM20L - which OBD version compatible?

Tags: toyota, obd, avensis

I seem to have problems with nailing down the interface version of the OBD socket in my car.

Is it OBD, OBD2 or EOBD compatible? I know the differences between them in theory, but there is no solid info on which the car is equipped with. I'm looking at purchasing several items for my car and their description is usually "EOBD compatible".

Those items will connect via OBD socket but their purposes are quite different from one another so what I'm really asking is are those standards interchangeable in terms of socket pin assignments?

Answer (score 1):

A Toyota Avensis sedan from 2002 is OBD compatible. Cheap bluetooth OBD dongles from amazon do work. It's most easily tested with the various mobile phone apps, they tend to be more user friendly than PC apps

Comment: Now the very good question comes to mind: how similar are verso and sedan? Because there's a lot of differences between them...

Comment: I always assumed the electronics would be quite similar, as far as I know they also share the same series of engines. A corolla and avensis from 2002 also share the engine block.